# How to only select and edit set ranges of values

Tags: python

Hi guys i have many tuples contained within the variable data,

what i want to do is take the data as an input, and from the 2148 set of data to 3506, ONLY if the value contained within the tuple contains (146, 28, 135) then 146 gets increased by one to become (147, 28, 135) this then should be looped so from 3506 +2148 ---- > 3506 +2148 + 1358 it does the same thing and again untill the end

how can i do a loop to achieve this

edit

sorry for the confusion

from 2148 means i only want to start changing values in the tuples, AFTER the 2148 set of tuples i that makes sense ?

and i want it to stop changing values at the 3506'th tuple

then 3506 +2148 ---- > 3506 +2148 + 1358

this meant i want it loop again think of it like a grid, starting at the value 5654 (3506 end of the last stop plus 2148 which does not need alterting) and ending at 7012 (the starting point for this row, plus 1358)

untill the end means the end of tuples

hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your terminology. What does "from the 2148 set of data to 3506" mean? What does "from 3506 +2148 ---- > 3506 +2148 + 3506" mean? What does "untill the end" mean?

Comment: edited above to try and make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an example of the data/tuple you are dealing with, the answer could be better.
A brute force way to it:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
  if i >= 2148 and i <= 3505:
    if data[i][0] == 146: # assuming each data element is a 3 element tuple
     data[i][0] += 1
```

Comment: If you guarantee that you will always have 3505 items to avoid raising an `IndexError`, you can get rid of the first condition for checking for the value of `i` by simply doing `for i in xrange(2148, 3506):`. You also can't change the value of a tuple, so you'd have to do `data[i] = (data[i][0] + 1, data[i][1], data[i][2])`.